# JQuery: need to make a dynamic functionality to implement an FAQ section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, hide

The idea is to have a list of questions. Each question is a link. When clicked, it will display the answer below it. i want to use simple JQuery functions to implement this. The question, is an  tag and the answer is in a  below it. Initially all the answer is hidden. When the question is clicked, the corresponding answer is displayed under it. When it is clicked again, the answer is hidden again.
so far the code i have written is like so:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
alert("start");
$(function(){
    alert("in func");
    $(".visible").show();
    $(".details").click( function(){
        alert("inside click function");
        var $id= $(this).attr("id");
        $id += 'd';
        alert($id);
        var $toShow = $(document.getElementById($id)); 
        if($toShow.hasClass("hidden"))
        {
        alert("in if");
            $toShow.show();
            $toShow.toggleClass("hidden");
            $toShow.toggleClass("visible");
        alert($toShow.hasClass("visible") + " " + $toShow.hasClass("hidden"));
        }
        else
        {
        alert("in else");
            $toShow.toggleClass("visible");
            $toShow.toggleClass("hidden");
        }
    });
    $(".hidden").hide();
});
alert("end");
</script>
<a href="" id="a1" class="details" data-type="a1d">click to show details</a><br/>
<div id="a1d" class="hidden"><p id="p1">.</p></div>
<a href="" id="a2" class="details" data-type="a2d">click too show details</a><br/>
<div id="a2d" class="hidden"><p id="p2">.</p></div>
<a href="" id="a3" class="details" data-type="a3d">click tooo show details</a><br/>
<div id="a3d" class="hidden"><p id="p2">.</p></div>
<a href="a2" id="a4" class="details" data-type="a4d">click toooo show details</a><br/>
<div id="a4d" class="hidden"><p id="p2">.</p></div>
<a href="a2" id="a5" class="details" data-type="a5d">click tooooo show details</a><br/>
<div id="a5d" class="hidden"><p id="p2">.</p></div>
```

Comment: Would the JQuery Accordion control be easier?

Comment: you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/c5xYB/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me you can do simply this:

```
$(".details").click( function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).nextAll('div:first').toggle(); // ".slideToggle();" for slide movement
});
```

#### [Demo @ Fiddle using your posted markup](http://jsfiddle.net/wKN2J/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. I didn't use your markup because I think it's a little messy. The idea is that you have a div with question and answer:

```
<div class="qa">
    <div class="question">
        Question #1
   </div>
    <div class="answer">
        Answer #1
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the answer is hidden with css:

```
.qa > .answer {
    display: none;
}
```

And when you click on the question, it opens or closes the corresponding answer:

```
$('.qa').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.answer').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

If you want it to close the other answers you could add there:

```
$('.qa').click(function() {
    $('.qa .question.open').toggleClass("open").siblings( ".answer" ).slideUp();

    $(this).find('.question').toggleClass("open");
    $(this).find('.answer').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Here's a fiddle with the second code: http://jsfiddle.net/sA9GN/1/